# Setup an extra, non-root syslog server as a systemd service

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I want to create a **systemd service**, which would start an *extra* instance of syslog (I assume **rsyslogd**, as this seems to be what's installed on my Xenial?). I want it to **listen on specified socket** (unprivileged) as a "syslog server", and dump all received logs to some file. I want it to run **unprivileged** (that is, as a non-root user).

Assuming I created new user `logdumper` and put the following lines in `/etc/systemd/syslog-server@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unprivileged syslog server on port %i

[Service]
User=logdumper
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -f /home/logdumper/rsyslogd-port-%i.conf \
    -i /home/logdumper/rsyslogd-port-%i.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

— **what should I put in `/home/logdumper/rsyslogd-port-%i.conf`?** Also, is my ExecStart OK?

Let's say I want it to listen on port 9999 (thus, %i=9999), and dump received data to `/home/logdumper/rsyslogd-port-9999.log`.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that something like below works for me as `rsyslogd-port-9999.conf`:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 9999

$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 9999

$ModLoad immark   # not sure what's this, but seems popular

$template Template_WithSrcHost,"%timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %FROMHOST% %syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"

*.* /home/logdumper/rsyslogd-port-9999.log;Template_WithSrcHost
```

I built this based on `man rsyslog.conf`. The `$template` directive is to add `%FROMHOST%`, which in my case is a better IP than `%HOSTNAME%`.